# can't login after creating a user in django, login function returns none

Tags: django, django-authentication

after I created a user in Django I then tried to login but can't.
i don't if its a setting that needs to be done or the problem is with the code.

this is my sign-in views

```
# def signin(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        pass1 = request.POST.get('password1')
        user = authenticate(email=email, password=pass1)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            fname = user.first_name
            return render (request, 'store.html', {'fname':fname})
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'invalid password or email')
            return render (request, 'signin.html')
    return render (request, 'signin.html')
```

and sign-up views
the pass2 says variable not accessed

```
def signup(request):
     
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        email = request.POST['email']
        fname = request.POST['fname']
        lname = request.POST['lname']
        pass1 = request.POST['password1']
        pass2 = request.POST['password2']

        myuser = User.objects.create_user(username, email, pass1, )
        myuser.first_name = fname 
        myuser.last_name = lname
        myuser.save()
        return redirect ('signin' )
    return render(request, 'signup.html')
```

this is my signup.html

```
<form method="post" action="signup">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="" class="form-label">Account name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="account name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="" class="form-label">Email address</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="email" placeholder="Enter email address" required>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="" class="form-label">First name </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="First name " required>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="" class="form-label">Last name </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="lname" placeholder="Last name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="password1" class="form-label">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password1" name="password1" placeholder=" Enter password" required>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="password2" class="form-label">Confirm Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password2" name="password2" placeholder=" Confirm password" required>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
```

ths is my signin.html

```
 <form method="post"  action="signin">
      {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="" class="form-label">Email address</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email " required>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="" class="form-label">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password1"  name="password1" placeholder="Enter password ">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
```

i don't where the error is coming from

Comment: Well your `singup` view clearly does not check if the two entered passwords match, that is one of the (many) reasons to use a form. Regardless can you show the database entry of the `auth_user` table?

Comment: Also share the form parts of the HTML templates (that will be `signup.html` and `signin.html`).

Comment: i have added the HTMLs, how do i access the auth_user table

Answer (score 0):

### Signup

In the signup, the reason `pass2` is not accessed is because you do not save pass2:

```py
myuser = User.objects.create_user(username, email, pass1, )
        myuser.first_name = fname 
        myuser.last_name = lname
        myuser.save()
#You don't have pass2 in here. 
#And as Willem Van Onsem said, you don't compare pass1 and pass2  before creating
```

You also **do not** have to `.save()` to create a user.
You can create a one-liner to create and save a user:

```py
User.objects.create_user(username=new_user, password=new_user_pwd,
 is_active=True, first_name=new_user_firstname)
```

### Signin / Login

In the signin function, you don't pass the request to authenticate.
You can do something like this:

```py
if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST["name"]
        password = request.POST["password"]

        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)
            return redirect('index')
```

Comment: i tried this but its  still not working